# Nearest neighbor matching in R

Tags: r, matching, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of 10,000 observations (numeric values). I want to generate 5,000 matched pairs from these observations using nearest neighbor matching. I am trying to think of an efficient way to do this.

My plan was to just sort them and then call observation i and i+1 a pair, for i = 1, 3,..., 9999, but this doesn't seem to be optimal since (depending on how I sort) lower/higher values will get closer matches.

Does anyone have some advice for a better way to proceed?

I have checked the R packages for matching. However, these all require me to indicate some treatment/control variable I don't have. I just want to match a list of numbers into pairs based on how close they are.

Thank you in advance.

structure of the data: c(0.732851696218165, -0.479344482931516, -0.139582120592376, 
0.477291542874127, 0.485648507877746, 0.226366004586156)

It's basically a vector of numbers.

Comment: We'll need to know at least a little about the structure of your data.  You can use `dput(head(your_data))` and paste the results into your question as an edit.  It sounds like you want to calculate the distance between each observation, but there are many ways to do that, and the right one depends upon context.

Comment: edited -- it's basically a vector of numbers, and I want to end up with matched pairs of numbers where the numbers are close together

Comment: So the distance between any two values is just `n1 - n2`.   Do you want the absolute value of the distance, or will the sign matter?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The absolute value of the distance is what I'm looking for.

Comment: May be this can help: `y<-combn(x); y[1,]-y[2,]` , where x is the vector in the example

Comment: @Metrics `combn`!  I knew there was something to make this task easier, but couldn't think of it.  It should be `y <- combn(x, 2)` for all 2 at a time combos.

Answer (score 0):

With my memory refreshed by @Metrics, and going in a slightly different direction to keep track of the original indices, here is a function:

```
mypairs <- function(x) {
    require("plyr")
    np <- length(x)
    g <- expand.grid(x, x)
    names(g) <- c("valueA", "valueB")
    g$absDiff <- abs(g$valueB - g$valueA)
    g$ind1 <- rep(1:np, np)
    g$ind2 <- rep(1:np, each = np)
    g <- arrange(g, absDiff)
    # remove g$diff == 0
    g <- g[-which(g$absDiff == 0),]
    # now every other value is a duplicate
    dups <- as.logical(1:nrow(g)%%2)
    g <- g[dups,]
    return(g)
    }

tst <- mypairs(rnorm(3)); tst
```

Which gives:

```
      valueA     valueB   absDiff ind1 ind2
4 -0.6813464 -0.5329252 0.1484212    3    2
6 -0.5329252  2.5917185 3.1246437    2    1
8 -0.6813464  2.5917185 3.2730649    3    1
```

`ind1` and `ind2` are the indices of the values in the original vector, which may of interest.  It's pretty slow since there are more combos than needed (`combn` doesn't have this problem, but it doesn't easily keep track of the original indices).  I'm thinking about how to speed it up but am currently drawing a blank.

Comment: If this is the kind of output you need, let me know.  I have a pretty good idea for a much faster version.

Answer (score 0):

You've no doubt moved on, but I'm here obsessing about this little logic problem and how to speed it up!  Here's an improved function that performs much better for long vectors.

```
mypairs <- function(x) {
    require("plyr")
    np <- length(x)
    M <- matrix(NA_real_, np, np)
    for (i in 1:np) {
        for (j in 1:np) { # compute only upper triangle
            if (j > i) M[i,j] <- x[j]-x[i]
            }
        }
    M <- abs(M)
    # unstack column by column
    d <- vector("numeric", np^2)
    for (i in 1:np) {
        d[(np*(i-1)+1):(np*i)] <- M[,i]
        }
    idx1 <- rep(1:np, np) # row index
    idx2 <- rep(1:np, each = np) # column index
    nope <- which(is.na(d))
    d <- d[-nope]
    idx1 <- idx1[-nope]
    idx2 <- idx2[-nope]
    df <- data.frame(dist = d, ptA = idx1, ptB = idx2)
    df <- arrange(df, d)
    df
    }
```

On my old Mac I get the following times (n points, seconds): 1000, 1.5; 2000, 6.4; 5000, 45; 10000, 213.  Not too bad.  Using a data table instead of a data frame at the end might save a little time.